# ledctl: identify empty slots

Tags: linux, sata, diskmanagement

Is there a way to get `ledctl` to identify empty drive sleds?

I can flash the light on an occupied slot by using `ledctl locate=/dev/sdb` (for example), but cannot figure out how to locate an/all empty sleds.

`man ledctl` suggests this is possible (emphasis mine):

> **locate**  Turns Locate LED associated with the given device(s) or *empty slot(s)* on.

My SATA controller is: `Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that that bit in the documentation was never a feature, and was in fact just misleading information in the documentation (per [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/intel/ledmon/issues/53)).

> It is not supported and this misleading information will be removed.

[This commit](https://github.com/intel/ledmon/commit/cbae54cdedbbbf7d0c56ad7a3f64e835881b2383) removes `or empty slot(s)` from that bit of the documentation and changes the line to read `Turns Locate LED associated with the given device(s) on.`

Also per that ticket, it is possible that this feature might be added in the future.